# Php match values between 2 arrays but foe like elements

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

I know there is `array_intersect` in `php` but what I want is to show like elements in two arrays.
For example:

```
array1 = [product, php]
array2 = [product management, html]
```

i want the resultant array to show `result = [product managemenet]`
array_intersect will give empty result here.

Comment: are you trying to make an intersection between 2 tables isn't it !!

Comment: kind of intersection but if any element of array 1 is found as part in array 2 it will need to show like i mentioned if array 1 has an element product and array 2 has an element product management the resultant should show product management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result=array();
$array1 = array('product','php');
$array2 = array('product management','html');

$srcharray = $array2;
foreach($array1 as $serchstr)
{
  foreach($srcharray as $key => $serchval)
  {
     if (strpos($serchval, $serchstr) !== false) {
     $result[] = $serchval;
     unset($srcharray[$key]);
     }
  } 
}
var_dump($result);
```

NOTE : If you need case sensitive matching.. use 'stripos' instead of 'strpos'.